# Systeminfo: Product ID

Tags: windows, registration, system-information

If you type *systeminfo* at the command prompt, there is a listing for *Product ID*.  Can someone explain what this is exactly, and would it make a good seed for a registration code algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe it's representative (or is) your windows product key.  Either way, all you really want is a [GUID](http://rtipton.wordpress.com/2007/09/30/generating-a-guid-in-c/).

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb878062.aspx

> You can find the product ID of your
>   installation by right clicking on My
>   Computer and choose Properties, then
>   viewing the General tab. You can also
>   find the product key in the registry
>   at:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\ CurrentVersion\ProductId.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good start. But (IMHO) you can use directly a GUID. 
Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint (read about **Active fingerprinting**)